# trusted SQL Server connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

When I attempt to make a connection from  my console app to my sqlExpress. I get the following error:

The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

I have:

    Switched users
    Switched passwords
    Switched Servers
    Switched Databases

I always get the same error. I am using VS 2010 and Sql Server 2005

Here is my current connection string

```
SqlDatabase sqlDatabase = new SqlDatabase(@"Server=localmachineName\SQLEXPRESS;   database=database1;user id=username; password=mypassword;");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is sql authorization enabled?

Check this if you haven't already: http://www.hosting.com/support/vps/windows/mixedmode/

Comment: I made the above change. I received a new error.

Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'mylogin'.

Comment: You probably have created a sql login (which gets you to the SQL server), but not given access for that login to a particular db.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx

Comment: Believe or not, I think I was using the wrong password the whole time. I went back in and changed the password with the enforced password policy box unchecked. My connection and edits to sql now work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `;` between `username` and `password`.

Comment: My mistake. I have been switching the string around often and didn't include the ; in the current code section. I went back and corrected the did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated, your connection string does not look correct. You can find examples at [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005). Alternatively, this KB [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889615) may be of some help.